# Values in Y axis are not passed in morris javascript

Tags: php, html, mysql, morris.js

I tried to pass the values from mysql through php using morris javascript to display a dynamic bar graph.But only value is x axis is being passed. Thus the graph is blank. I did all researches by I could not find it. I need your help. I am new to programming.

```js
Morris.Bar({
 element : 'chart',
 data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
 xkey:'gp_submit',
 ykeys:['cnt'],
 labels:['Submitted','cnt'],
 hideHover:'auto',
 stacked:true
});
```

```css
<?php $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hr");
$query = "SELECT gp_submit AS dt, name AS cnt FROM `emp_det` where gp_submit>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) GROUP BY gp_submit";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $chart_data .= "{ gp_submit:'".$row["dt"]."', cnt:'".$row["cnt"]."'}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
```

```html
<div id="chart" style="width:100%; height:280px;"></div>
```

Comment: can you also add your query result so we can see the data you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not passing there a proper `JSON`

Try Like this

```
$chart_data  = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $chart_data []['gp_submit']= $row["dt"];
 $chart_data[]['cnt]  = $row["cnt"];
}
```

And in JS:

```
Morris.Bar({
 element : 'chart',
 data:<?php echo json_encode($chart_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>,
 xkey:'gp_submit',
 ykeys:['cnt'],
 labels:['Submitted','cnt'],
 hideHover:'auto',
 stacked:true
});
```

it should work;

Comment: Thank you. But it doesnt work. When I executed the same the x axis values are not passed as well

Answer (score 0):

```
new Morris.Bar({
     element: "bargraph",
     data: d_data,//getBarData(data,periodvalue,year),//data,
     xkey: "day",
     ykeys: ["total","confirm"],
     xLabels:'day Month',
     labels: [total,confirm],
     barColors: ['#0b62a4','#7BB661']
});

Morris.Bar({
    element : 'chart',
    data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
    xkey:'gp_submit',
    ykeys:['here you haveto put value','cnt'],
    labels:['Submitted','cnt'],
    hideHover:'auto',
    stacked:true
});
```